# Can I run my own javascript on a (loaded) page?

Tags: javascript, browser

Can I run my own javascript code in a browser when viewing a page?

For example I have page index.html. In that I want to run this javascript function

```
function myFunction()
{

 alert("Say Hi");

}
```

I want to call this function through some browser interface because I don't have access to the source code of the web.

Comment: why not. what means by `my own javascript` ?

Comment: I'd think you'd have seen enough badly phrased questions by now to know one before you click the "Post Your Question" button...

Comment: Question edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to inject? I'm here trying to prevent it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Just how depends on which browser you're using:

- For Chrome and Safari you'll use the built-in Web Inspector—see the instructions on [this page](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector).
- Firefox has the built-in [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Web_Console), but the more advanced add-on [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is very popular.
- The Internet Explorer equivalent is [Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you can launch with F12.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet), the javascript console or a browser plugin to run your own code in an already loaded page.

[Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) is a browser plugin for Firefox that provides a framework for running your own javascript code in other web pages that are already loaded.

Answer (score 6):

You can either simply type it into the JavaScript console for your browser, or for trivial things, you can use the `javascript:` protocol handler.

Answer (score 1):

One of the first links when searching on google - [Get Started With Greasemonkey](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_greasemonkey/)